# Keras accuracy is different between model and classification report for binary output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is how I loaded the data which are 2 folders with image data:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_folder,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(dim, dim))

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_folder,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(dim, dim))
```

The loading of the training data from the folder gives

```
Found 6457 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 5812 files for training.
Found 6457 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 645 files for validation.
```

Here is how I trained my model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0.1, patience=5)

model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epc,
    callbacks=[es])
```

Here is how I got the results:

```
y_pred = model.predict(val_ds)
predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
    
print(classification_report(true_categories, predicted_categories ))
```

The Contradicting outputs are:

```
Epoch 1/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 44ms/step - loss: 0.6617 - accuracy: 0.5139 - val_loss: 0.6466 - val_accuracy: 0.3442
Epoch 2/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 46ms/step - loss: 0.6613 - accuracy: 0.5712 - val_loss: 0.6460 - val_accuracy: 0.6558
Epoch 3/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 44ms/step - loss: 0.6611 - accuracy: 0.5594 - val_loss: 0.6474 - val_accuracy: 0.3442
Epoch 4/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 46ms/step - loss: 0.6315 - accuracy: 0.6504 - val_loss: 0.4623 - val_accuracy: 0.9690
Epoch 5/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 46ms/step - loss: 0.4780 - accuracy: 0.9554 - val_loss: 0.4597 - val_accuracy: 0.9690
Epoch 6/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 45ms/step - loss: 0.4831 - accuracy: 0.9434 - val_loss: 0.4517 - val_accuracy: 0.9845
Epoch 7/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 45ms/step - loss: 0.4720 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.4546 - val_accuracy: 0.9736
Epoch 8/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 44ms/step - loss: 0.4719 - accuracy: 0.9652 - val_loss: 0.4507 - val_accuracy: 0.9860
Epoch 9/100
182/182 [==============================] - 8s 44ms/step - loss: 0.4747 - accuracy: 0.9597 - val_loss: 0.4528 - val_accuracy: 0.9814

              precision    recall  f1-score   support
           0       0.34      1.00      0.51       222
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       423
    accuracy                           0.34       645
   macro avg       0.17      0.50      0.26       645
weighted avg       0.12      0.34      0.18       645
```

Otherwise, I get a different answer every time I execute it

[image]

Can someone please please why is the classification report has an accuracy of 34% while the model val_accuracy is 0.94%?

Comment: Can you add your model?

Comment: Have you tried adding `precision` , or `recall` along with `accuracy` while you compiled your model?

Comment: @Frightera I added the model

Comment: @M.Innat I have added how I compiled the model, can you please highlight how you insert those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory
```

method has a parameter called `label_mode` and its default value is `int` which is suitable for `sparse_categoricalcrossentropy` etc. It should be changed into `label_model = binary` if the classification is binary classification.

Contradiction is here:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

With `sigmoid` your outputs consist of a list with a shape of `(1,)`. And when you take `argmax` of that list it is always returning zero as index because of the list has only one index. So you need to apply some threshold method when using `sigmoid`. Sigmoid squeezes outputs into a range of [0,1]. So you can do:

```
predicted_categories = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in y_pred]
```

or using numpy:

```
predicted_categories = np.where(y_pred > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

where 0.5 is the threshold.

This means if predicted value is bigger than `0.5` then it will belong to second class. You can adjust the threshold depending on your needings.

Comment: Here is what I did, it actually gives me a different answer everytime I execute it `predicted_categories = [1 * (x[0] >= 0.5) for x in y_pred]
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)

print(classification_report(true_categories, predicted_categories))`

Comment: in the question I mistakenly use `predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)` and `y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)`, so I will remove the y_pred_pool

Comment: I forgot to mention `image_dataset_from_directory` has a label mode and it is defaulted to `int`. Can you try changing it to `label_mode = binary`?

Comment: I am re-training it will take some time, but it seems like you are right. The problem was two-fold, first how I calculated the `predicted_categories` and second changing it to `label_mode = binary`

Comment: I will edit the answer to also reflect this.

Comment: I have another question while its training, in the data folder it says `Found 6457 files belonging to 2 classes.` should I be using `    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') or     tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')` ?

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` since you specified `label_mode = binary`. If you can one hot encode them you can use `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')`. In **multi-class** classification you don't want to use a Dense layer contaning 2 neurons with a sigmoid activation.