# How can I draw the Confusion Matrix when using image_dataset_from_directory in Tensorflow2.x?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, tensorflow2.x

My TF version is 2.9 and Python 3.8.

I have built an image binary classification CNN model and I am trying to get a confusion matrix.

The dataset structure is as follows.

```
train/
│------ benign/
│------ normal/ 

test/
│------ benign/
│------ normal/
```

The dataset configuration is as follows.

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1337,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

test_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = test_data_dir,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    seed=1337,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

I wrote the code referring to the following link to get the confusion matrix.
[Reference Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622210/how-to-extract-classes-from-prefetched-dataset-in-tensorflow-for-confusion-matri)

And this is my code about the confusion matrix.

```
predictions = model.predict(test_ds)

y_pred = []
y_true = []

# iterate over the dataset
for image_batch, label_batch in test_ds:   # use dataset.unbatch() with repeat
   # append true labels
   y_true.append(label_batch)
   # compute predictions
   preds = model.predict(image_batch)
   # append predicted labels
   y_pred.append(np.argmax(preds, axis = - 1))

# convert the true and predicted labels into tensors
true_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_true], axis = 0)
predicted_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_pred], axis = 0)


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(true_labels, predicted_labels)
print(cm)
```

y_pred and y_true were obtained from test_ds as above, and the results of confusion matrix were as follows.

```
[[200 0]
  [200 0]]
```

So I tried outputting true_labels and predicted_labels, and confirmed that predicted_labels are both 0 as follows.

```
print(true_labels)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(400,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 1])>
```

```
print(predicted_labels)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(400,), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)>
```

I'm not sure why predicted_labels are all zero.

But this is wrong. I think the following results are correct.

```
[[200 0]
  [0 200]]
```

What is wrong? I've been struggling for a few days. Please please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is correct... You're predicting all 0's so half of your values will be correct (TP) and half will be wrong (FP), given your data, thus, getting [[200 0] [200 0]]. You don't have TN or FN because you never predicted 1. If you're not expecting these results, it's a model or training related issue. This is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: @KevinM thank you for your answer.
but, absolutely this is not correct.

I found the solution my problem.
the problem was this code. y_pred.append(np.argmax(preds, axis = - 1))

Comment: @KevinM In a binary classification model using the sigmoid function, I found that all values can be zero when using np.argmax.

In the last output, if the activation function is sigmoid, it is necessary to specify which class it belongs to by using the threshold value.

In my case I solved the problem through code y_pred.append(np.where(preds > 0.5, 1, 0))

array([[180, 20],
        [ 10, 190]])>

In fact, we were able to get the following confusion matrix result:

Finally, It makes it clear that my question is not out of scope.

Comment: @KevinM I have referred the following link to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374889/keras-accuracy-is-different-between-model-and-classification-report-for-binary-o

Answer (score 1):

In case of Image Binary Classification, threshold should be used to obtain predict label after model.predict(test_ds). I found that modifying the code in my question `y_pred.append(np.argmax(preds, axis = - 1))` to `y_pred.append(np.where(preds > threshold, 1, 0))` solved the problem. Hope it was helpful to someone.